# onScroll listener does not working in TableView in JavaFX 2

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use the onScroll event listener of a TableView component:

**FXML:**

```
<TableView fx:id="table" onScroll="#doSomething" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

**Java Controller:**

```
@FXML
void doSomething(ActionEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("Object: " + event.getSource());
}
```

But it does not working! What I'm doing wrong?

I need to capture the vertical scroller to manually control the scroll position and fetch related data according to scroll down or up.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what might be happening is that the TableView includes itself is consuming the scroll event and processing it internally, so it never gets to your application handler.

Initially, I thought you might want to use [`onScrollTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#onScrollToProperty) rather than [`onScroll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onScrollProperty), but that doesn't seem to really address the issue.

I think the solution which works is to apply a filter on the scroll event.

In addition, you can write code that makes use of with [`scrollTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo-int-) calls to "manually control the scroll position".

Here is some sample code you can try (Java 8):

*TableScrollerApp.java*

```
package finder;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableScrollerApp extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("tablescroller.fxml")
        );
        Parent parent = loader.load();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(parent)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

*TableScrollerController.java*

```
package finder;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollToEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TableScrollerController {
    private static final String[] fruitNames = {
            "apples", "oranges", "pears", "peaches", 
            "guavas", "bananas", "jackfruit", "durians"
    };

    @FXML
    private TableView<Fruit> fruitsTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fruit, String> fruitsColumn;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        fruitsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        fruitsTable.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, event ->
                System.out.println("Coded scroll filter: " + event)
        );

        fruitsTable.getItems().setAll(
                Arrays.stream(fruitNames)
                        .map(Fruit::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );

        fruitsTable.scrollTo(5);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void onScrollHandler(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
        System.out.println("FXML referenced scroll handler: " + scrollEvent);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void onScrollToHandler(ScrollToEvent<Integer> scrollToEvent) {
        System.out.println("FXML referenced onScroll handler: " + scrollToEvent);
    }

    public static class Fruit {
        private ReadOnlyStringWrapper name;

        public Fruit(String name) {
            this.name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

*tablescroller.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<TableView fx:id="fruitsTable" 
           maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
           minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
           onScroll="#onScrollHandler" 
           onScrollTo="#onScrollToHandler" 
           prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="250.0" 
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
           fx:controller="finder.TableScrollerController">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="fruitsColumn" 
                 maxWidth="800.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="-1.0" 
                 text="Fruits" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Fantastic @jewelsea! Where you adds the filter helped me to do exactly what I need: get the vertical ScrollBar instance. With it in hands, I was able to detect the scroll position and fetch data when the scroll is in the end.
Thank you very much!