# Javafx TableView Scroll not working

Tags: javafx

Guys I am trying to make an application involving a tableview. I want my program to run a certain method when the user is scrolling, stopped scrolling, or scrolled to the bottom of the page in the TableView. I was trying to the use the on Scroll, on Scroll Finished in Scene Builder, but nothing happens.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mYBh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZyZs.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackOverFlow community , please read how to post [mcve].

Comment: Maybe is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789525/onscroll-listener-does-not-working-in-tableview-in-javafx-2